# Pegar ID inserido por Ajax

Tags: ajax, json

Tenho uma função que incluo um cadastro, e ao incluir eu chamo outra função, nesta outra função preciso passar o último ID incluído, como posso fazer isso ?

```js
function SalvarHorario() {


    //NomeHorario
    var nome = $("#Nome").val();

    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var tokenadr = $('form[action="/Horario/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var headers = {};
    var headersadr = {};
    headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
    headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

    //Gravar
    var url = "/Horario/Create";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "POST"
        , datatype: "json"
        , headers: headersadr
        , data: { Id: 0, Nome: nome, __RequestVerificationToken: token }
        , success: function (data) {
            //if (data.Resultado > 0) {
            ListarItens(data.Resultado);
            //}
        }
    });
}
```

Essa função funciona, só que para a função ListarItens preciso passar o idHorario, que acabou de ser incluído, de todas as formas que tento, ele vai nulo. Segue como funciona a Listar Itens.

```js
function ListarItens(idHorario) {

    var url = "/HorarioItem/Create";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: idHorario }
        , datatype: "html"
        , success: function (data) {
            var divItens = $("#divItens");
            divItens.empty();
            divItens.show();
            divItens.html(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Tentei idHorario = data, idHorario = data.Id, idHorario = data.Resultado.
Ao incluir já preciso passar este id para a outra função. Estou trabalhando com MVC Core. Obrigado.

Comment: Amigo você terá de pegar na inserção do seu registro e retornar no response do request, no sql server se chama scope_identity  e no mysql é last_inserted_id.

Comment: Utilizo MVC Core, o Razor CRUD, eu já tenho a página pronta, tenho que fazer a função logo após incluir ? Seria isso ? Desculpe, sou nova na linguagem, ainda estou apanhando rs

Comment: O `data.Resultado` está vindo vazio? Tente dar um `console.log(data.Resultado)` e veja se o resultado está realmente chegando na função, vinda do servidor.

Comment: Sim, está vindo undefined ..

Comment: Então não está chegando o que você realmente precisa. Faça `console.log(data)` e veja o que retorna.

Comment: Ele retorna undefined, ele está salvando no banco com a função, porém ele não retorna o id.

Comment: Você retorna algo no final da função Create do Controller Horario?